# SSL_read fails 2nd time

Tags: java, openssl, ssl

I've an openssl client talking ssl. The client was previously talking to an openssl server and everything was fine and dandy. We're now rewriting the server in java and we're seeing the following happen.

1) connecting to server WORKS

2) handshake WORKS

3) 1st request WORKS

4) 1st response WORKS

5) 2nd request WORKS

6) 2nd response FAILS

7) 3rd request WORKS

8) 3rd response FAILS

The 2nd response is about 130bytes encrypted and (should be) around 100bytes unencrypted. The client is successfully reading all those 130 bytes from the tcp socket, but after putting it threw SSL_read (like 1st respone), it only outputs 1 byte. No error after calling SSL_get_error...just 1 byte is returned successfully. I call SSL_pending directly afterwards and it returns 0.

The 3rd response now returns -1 SSL_ERROR_SSL "decryption failed or bad record mac"

I'm brand new to openssl and ive been battling this issue for several hours now. Any ideas would be much appreciated

UPDATE: relevant code

```
...
BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buff(sbuf, bufoutlen);
BIO_set_mem_close(bio,BIO_NOCLOSE);
ssl->rbio=bio;
int len = SSL_read(ssl, bufout, sbuflen); //<<return 1 even though buf has 130bytes
printf("pending=%d\n",SSL_pending(ssl)); //<<returns 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on things you can't rely on. Java may buffer the response differently into its SSL layer, which would result in different-length SSL messages being received. You can't rely on the length of any read over SSL or TCP, they are byte-stream protocols, in the case of SSL at least at the level of the API. You have to read in a loop until you have everything you need.

Comment: im well aware of packet fragmentation, this is not it.

Comment: @justonemailjustonemail I didn't say anything about packet fragmentation. You're not in any position to be definitive about what is and isn't the answer, given that you are asking the question. It's your code that doesn't work, not mine.